# Orange Money Payment - React Native

Tags: react-native, mobile, payment-gateway, payment-processing, orange-pi

Mobile wallet payment integration with my React Native app. the app will be used in Guinea conkary so I gotta find a gateway that is supported right there, users will pay from their bank account to 2 different bank accounts at once, if someone can help, I would appreciate that.

I checked for orange money API but customer support are not replying and found some other gateways but not supported in that region of Guinea Conkary. Thank you in advance.